# Блокировка таблицы

Tags: php, mysql

посте вот такого запроса:

```
$update="LOCK TABLES users_cash WRITE;";
$update.="UPDATE users_cash SET end='1' WHERE id='48';";
$update.="UPDATE users_cash SET end='1' WHERE id='45';";
$update.="UPDATE users_cash SET end='1' WHERE id='75';";
$update.="UPDATE users_cash SET end='1' WHERE id='77';";
$update.="UNLOCK TABLES;";
mysql_query($update);
```

Выдаёт такую ошибку:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to
> your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near 'UPDATE
> users_cash SET end='1' WHERE
> id='48';UPDATE users_cash SET end='1'
> WHERE ' at line 1

В чём моя ошибка?

Comment: может проще...

    UPDATE users_cash SET end='1' WHERE id in (48,45,75,77);

Comment: а, еще в доках по функции можно найти забавную строчку о том, что использование ";" как терминирующего оператора (а не в составе строки) запрещено - очевидно, чтобы запретить таким образом инъекции.

Answer (score 1):

Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) или [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.php). Смотрите также инструкцию [MySQL: выбор API](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) и [соответствующий FAQ](http://php.net/manual/ru/faq.databases.php) для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной функции:

- [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php)
- [PDO::query()](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.query.php)

Answer (score 0):

дам наводку - `MySQL транзакции`. В гугле найдете необходимые примеры реализации.